# SBT alternative for maven's dependencyManagement

Tags: maven, sbt

In our multi-project codebase, we are using Maven as build framework.
However, we have a Play framework based module, for which we have to use SBT build.

In Maven projects, we have dependencyManagement configured through another project called "version" and included in pom.xml, as follows.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxx.release</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxx-version</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This makes sure to pull correct version of dependency jars for the specific build.

Is there a way to achieve same with SBT?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an in-house sbt plugin that defines something like the follows:

```scala
package com.example

import sbt._

object Dependencies {
  // versions
  lazy val akkaVersion = "2.5.22"

  // libraries
  val akkaActor = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion
  val akkaCluster = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion
}
```

After adding the plugin to your Play app, you can write inside `build.sbt` as follows:

```scala
import com.example.Dependencies._
```

and `akkaActor` will be available as a name.